# Proving if a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $ \mathbb R^2$ is convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

Say $f(x,y)$ = [ $x + y $$\quad$ $ 2x + 7y$ ] , how do I prove that this function is convex?

I know in order to prove that a function from $R^2$ --> $R^1$ is convex then the Hessian of that function has to be pos-semi-def. So is it then sufficient to say that if,

$f(x,y) = x + y$ $\quad$ is convex

and

$f(x,y) = 2x+7y$ $\quad$ is convex,

then

$f(x,y)$ = [$x+y$ $\quad$ $2x+7y$] $\quad$ is also convex?

My intuition says yes, but I haven't been able to find anything supporting this online.

Comment: You can say that affine change of convex function is convex function,and you can check the hessian which will be the zero matrix

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I don't think you can call such a function convex - as the definition is only for real valued functions

Comment: Defining convexity of a function with values in $\mathbb R^{2}$ requires an ordering on $\mathbb R^{2}$

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a function $f: \mathbf{X}\to\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is convex if $\text{epi}f$ is a convex set. Therefore convexity is a definition which applies to real-valued functions only. Vector-valued functions simply don't posses the property of being be convex or not.